# Циклическая переадресация

Tags: google-chrome, php

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при использовании модуля авторизации в хроме возникает ошибка "На странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация", в опере всё отлично работает, эксплорер вообще виснет. Код блока:

```
<?
$user_status = '0'; // обнуляем статус пользователя, 0 - пользователь не авторизован

// запрещаем прямой вызов файла
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == NULL) {
    header ('Location: /admin/');
}

if (isset ($_COOKIE['Login']) || isset ($_COOKIE['Password'])) {
    $_COOKIE['Login']    = htmlspecialchars ($_COOKIE['Login']);
    $_COOKIE['Password'] = htmlspecialchars ($_COOKIE['Password']);
}

// читаем куки и смотрим, есть ли в базе пользователь с таким паролем, 
// и проверяем были ли нажаты кнопки вход или выход
if (isset ($_COOKIE['Login']) && 
    isset ($_COOKIE['Password']) && 
    empty ($_POST['auth']) && 
    empty ($_GET['exit'])) {

    // запрос
    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "_users` 
         WHERE `login` = '" . $_COOKIE['Login'] . "' 
         && `password` = '" . $_COOKIE['Password'] . "'");

    // если есть совпадение, авторизуем пользователя
    if (mysql_num_rows ($sql) > 0) {

        // собираем все данные о пользователе в массив
        $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array ($sql);

        // устанавливаем куки
        SetCookie ("Login",    $userinfo['login']);
        SetCookie ("Password", $userinfo['password']);

        $user_status = '1'; // статус пользователя, 1 - авторизован админ
    }
}

// если была нажата кнопка из формы авторизации
if ($_POST['auth']) {

    // ищем совпадение пары логин-пароль в таблице
    $auth = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "_users` 
          WHERE `login` = '" . $_POST['login'] . "' 
          && `password` = '" . $_POST ['pass'] . "'");

    // если есть совпадение, авторизуем пользователя
    if (mysql_num_rows($auth) > '0'){

        // собираем все данные о пользователе в массив
        $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array ($auth);

        // устанавливаем куки
        SetCookie ('Login',    $_POST['login']);
        SetCookie ('Password', $_POST['pass']);

        $user_status = '1'; // статус пользователя, 1 - авторизован админ
    } else { // если если пара логин-пароль не совпала, выводим сообщение об ошибке
        echo "Такой пользователь не существует или пароль не верный.";
    }
}

// если нажата кнопка выход
if ($_GET['exit']) {

    // удаляем куки
    SetCookie ('Login',    $_POST['login']);
    SetCookie ('Password', $_POST['pass']);
}

// если статус пользователя не изменился, выводим форму авторизации 
if ($user_status == '0') {

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/inc/header.php'; // шапка админки
?>

<!-- форма авторизации -->
<div style="position:absolute;width:260px;left:50%;top:50%;
margin-left:-150px;margin-top:-100px;background:#777;color:#eee;
border:solid 1px black;padding:10px;
font-family:Tahoma,Arial,FreeSans,Garuda,Utkal,sans-serif;overflow:auto">
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        Логин:<br>
        <input type="text" name="login" style="width:250px">
        <br><br>
        Пароль:<br>
        <input type="password" name="pass" style="width:250px">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="auth" value="Войти">
    </form>
</div>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: @Mariya, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @Mariya, что хранится в файле admin/inc/header.php?

Comment: В файле admin/inc/header.php? след код.
<?
if ($user_status == '0') {
    header ('Location: /admin/'); // запрещаем прямое обращение к файлу
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>
    <title><? if (@$admin_title) {echo $admin_title . " - ";} ?> Панель управления сайтом</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/admin/style.css">
<?
if ($_GET['event'] == 'add' || $_GET['event'] == 'edit') {
?>
 <?
}
?>
</head>

Comment: **Warning:** Вас легко взломают, подставив в куки SQL-инъекцию.

Comment: @sergiks, Я думаю, что данный человек пишет для себя - иначе не может быть, иначе это epic fail.

Comment: Не подскажете тогда надежный модуль авторизации?

Comment: sergiks, а не подскажете как обойти эту уязвимость?

Comment: SetCookie ('Login',    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']));
    SetCookie ('Password', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));

Подойдет вот такой способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка тут. Всегда отсутствует реферрер.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == NULL) {
    header ('Location: /admin/');
}
```